# Simple and compact chat user-interface

Tags: android

I am developing a multiplayer android game and I am trying to add a chat UI for players to talk to eachother.

I don't want this chat UI always visible because of space issues, I'd like there to be a tab that you can press or slide that will bring the chat menu up. I have a sketch so you can see what I mean...

[image]

How can I go about implementing this in android.

I know I am going to need to use EditText and TextView etc but How can I get the sliding thing to work.

EDIT: I'm not looking for a flat out answer. I just need guidance. What widgets, methods etc should I be studying

Comment: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: @CommonsWare Well that is extremely convenient and is exactly what I was looking for. If you post as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be a `SlidingDrawer` in the Android SDK. It is officially deprecated and, to be honest, was never that good.

There is nothing in the Android SDK that directly replaces the old `SlidingDrawer`. The leading third-party implementation seems to be [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), though there are probably others floating around.

Comment: SlidingDrawer deprecated since API level 17. More general solution is a NavigationDrawer.

Comment: @YevgenKulik: What the question is asking for is not a navigation drawer.